# What is the proper way of checking if element exists and is true in a python dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

```
someDict = {'foo': True}
if 'foo' in someDict and someDict['foo']:
    print 'success'
```

Following code works fine. I'm just wondering if there is a better/shorter way of checking if key exists and its value is true.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`someDict.get('foo')`

This will return None if `foo` is not in `someDict`, otherwise it will return the value found. You can optionally pass a second argument which will be the value returned if it does not exist.

Comment: +1 for mentioning you can specify the optional argument. I personally prefer `someDict.get('foo', False)` so the intent is more obvious, but either way works.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. If you're doing this a lot, you may want to write a function to do it, though.

```
def ExistsTrue(d, name):
    return name in d and bool(d[name])
# usage
ExistsTrue(someDict, 'foo')
```

I put the `bool` cast in there so the function only returns `True` or `False`.